# When i run my c++ code it shows more other things with output

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Here is the problem;

When I run my c++ code it shows more other things with output, But I need only the output(Hello world)

[image]

Comment: Please show the code and the output in the question.

Comment: I attach a picture

Comment: Put an `endl` at the end. `cout << "Hello world" << endl;`

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: That's the command to compile and run the code... A series of powershell commands that you probably copy-pasted from somewhere. VsCode has bultin support for compiling stuff and running programms, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

Comment: Who's on 17th.cpp